# Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar / Fatal Force Close Error - Android / Java

Tags: android, out-of-memory, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm getting an error when attempting to display a progress bar and an image in my android application:

```
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Process: com.example.app, PID: 1565
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Download}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.example.app.Download.onCreate(Download.java:78)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     ... 11 more
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     ... 25 more
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:294)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:246)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:242)
07-02 12:33:55.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     ... 28 more
```

The error appears to crash at Line 78: `setContentView(R.layout.download);`

but it also references an out of memory issue which I've been able to resolve in the past by implementing the following:

```
 @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.ListView_layout));
        System.gc();
        }

        private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
            if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }
```

However in this instance the application is still crashing after doing so and I am unsure why.

### Source:

http://pastebin.com/KqwhFxYk

Comment: From the looks of your stack trace, I would suspect you are trying to load a custom bitmap drawable for your progress bar and it is absolutely huge.  Can you report back on what bitmap you're associating with the progress bar and how big it is?

Comment: button_download = 508 x 121 

imageView1 = 1,000px × 1,500px

Comment: Assuming a depth of 24 bits per pixel, the larger of your images would be over 4 MB in memory.  Available max heap size for an android app varies by phone between 16MB and 256MB.  Looks like you were near the max heap size for your app just before you tried to load this layout.  You can band-aid fix it by specifying android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest, but I would strongly suggest pre-scaling/optimizing the bit depth of your image drawables as a real first step towards limiting the amount of memory your app consumes.

Comment: How might I go about prescaling? The images are coming down from IMDB - so they're pretty big... (I tried adding android:largeHeap="true" as a quick band-aid fix - but it's still crashing [thank you for your insight btw])

Comment: I'd search for resize bitmap decoded from URL.  There are quite a few items addressing this very issue here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add below code to manifest file in application tag:
`android:largeHeap="true"`

i have encountered by this problem when i tested my own app on android 5 or above.